# Compressing on apache server

Tags: php, .htaccess, gzip

I have problem with my .htaccess and compressing content. Mod Rewrite works well but gzip or deflate compression not working. This is my code . Its not working.

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

[PHP SERVER CONFIG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMVIo.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/555140/apache-mod-deflate-does-not-compress-php-output

Comment: Wow thanks [link](http://cdn.makeagif.com/media/8-15-2015/3XiiFV.gif)